# I am loading javascript in webview.loadURL but javascript is not loading with release build for debug and publish it's working fine

Tags: java, android, webview

## The webview is loading javascript file both in debug and publish build but not working in Release build

### Here is my java part of code

```
webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //change detected
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    //java script is used here
    //change

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
   // settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");


    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", getString(R.string.loading_text));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(getContext()), "android");
    }
    else
    {
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(getContext()), "android");
    }
    
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            if (url.contains("ReturnUrl") && mContext != null) {
                ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String js = "javascript:android.opbel(document.getElementById('EReceipt').value);";
                        webview.loadUrl(js);
                    }
                    //
                });
```

### Here is the part of build.gradle file for release, i also did some changes in proguard.pro file but it's not working too

```
     release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "String", "LET_CHANNEL", "\"\""
        proguardFiles(file("$buildDir/../proguard").listFiles())
        ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath = "$buildDir/../beta_distribution_emails_debug.txt"
        //buildConfigField "String", "PREFS_TOKEN", "\"""
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_ROOT_URL", "\"""
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "PRODUCTION", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "ADJUST_TOKEN", keystoreProperties['adjustToken']
        buildConfigField "String", "KP", keystoreProperties['sslKeystorePass']
        buildConfigField "String", "MAPS", "\"""
    }
```

## This is my proguard file i did some changes but not success

```
    -keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
#Warnings to be removed. Otherwise maven plugin stops, but not dangerous
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
-dontwarn com.sun.istack.internal.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn java.util.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.**

-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator

-keepclassmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.paybill.PayBillFragment.MyJavascriptInterface {
  public *;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.paybill.PayBillFragment.MyJavascriptInterface
-keep public class * implements com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.paybill.PayBillFragment.MyJavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.paybill.PayBillFragment.MyJavascriptInterface{
    <methods>;
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod


-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.*$MyJavascriptInterface {
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.*$JavaScriptInterface {
    *;
}

-keep public class **.*$MyJavascriptInteface
-keep public class **.*$JavaScriptInterface

-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
-keep class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.model.* { *; }
-keep class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.vo.* { *; }
-keep class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.nmodel.* { *; }
-keep class pl.droidsonroids.gif.** { *; }
-keep class rx.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }

# Ignore warnings: We are not using DOM model
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer

# Keep Jackson stuff
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }
-keep class com.netmera.** { *; }

# Keep Retrofit
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @retrofit.** *;
}
-keep class com.useinsider.insider.** { *; }

-dontwarn info.guardianproject.netcipher.**

-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.anket.edit.RadioSingleSelectRenderer.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.anket.view.AnketViewFragment.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.rest.services.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.utils.RealmHelper.** {*;}
-keep class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.utils.AppVersion {*;}
-keep class com.enerjisa.perakende.mobilislem.fragments.paybill.**{*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class cn.com.broadlink.** {*;}

-keep class com.netmera.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keep public class * implements com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
**[] $VALUES;
public *;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class com.shockwave.**
-keepclassmembers class com.shockwave.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { zza(...); }
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue?